# Could not able to retrieve VersionData from Content Version after insert of ContentDocument

Tags: apex, contentversion, contentdocument, after-trigger, contentdocumentlink

I am trying to retrieve the body of ContentDocument after insert.
Below is my code.My trigger is on ContentDocument (After Insert)

```
 public static void syncContentDocument(List<ContentDocument> documentList) {

        for (ContentDocument attach : documentList) {
            contentIds.add(attach.id);
        }
        //create content document body map
        for (ContentVersion content : [SELECT Id,Title,VersionData FROM ContentVersion WHERE ContentDocumentId IN : contentIds AND IsLatest = true]) {
            bodyContent.put(content.Id, content.VersionData);
        }
        System.debug('contentIds' + contentIds);
        System.debug('bodyContent' + bodyContent);

}
```

But I am getting empty result from debug logs. Could anyone please help me to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Speaking across Salesforce, child objects are not available for query during the `insert` event for their parents. `ContentDocument` is the parent object for one or many `ContentVersion` records; you will not be able to query those `ContentVersion` objects during the `after insert` event for their parent `ContentDocument`s. Likewise, you won't be able to access `Contact` records parented under an `Account` during the `insert` event of the `Account.

Instead, consider writing a trigger against `ContentVersion` `insert` events, when you will be able to access these records and their contained data.

Comment: Hi David.. As you told I have tried the trigger on ContentVersion. I can able to get the records of other fields like( title,id) BUT ContentVersion is still empty.

Comment: public static void syncContentDocument(List<ContentVersion> documentList) {
for (ContentVersion attach : documentList) {
            bodyContent.put(attach.id, attach.VersionData);
        }

         System.debug('bodyContent' + bodyContent);
}
here Id is coming But ContentVersion is empty

Comment: Hi Finally I got the versionData like this
VersionData=Blob[100730]
But how can I get the file body from this?

Comment: @jury I think you should raise a separate question or you may search for other question on how to convert blob to a string value.

Comment: Okay. Thank You !!